# Parsear en PHP un XML que contiene el caracter '

Tags: php, xml

Buenas tardes a todos.

He hecho un script en php para parsear un fichero XML pero este fichero en algunos de sus campos contiene el caracter ', que entra en conflcito con el código PHP. De momento he borrado este caracter del fichero XML pero me gustaría que se almacenase en la BD.

No sé si debo modificar el fichero XML, poniendo algo delante del caracter para que cuando lo lea el script no entre en conflcito, o debo meter algo en el script de php para que lo libre. ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Dejo el script php:

```
$fichero = "./obras.xml";
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichero))
{
    echo "No se ha podido cargar el archivo <br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "El archivo se ha cargado correctamente <br>";
}

include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

function Mayus($variable) {
$variable = strtr(strtoupper($variable),"àèìòùáéíóúçñäëïöü","ÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÇÑÄËÏÖÜ");
return $variable;
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

foreach ($xml as $obra)
{
    $obra = (array) $obra;
    $ninv = $obra['ninventario'];

    $ninv = Mayus($ninv);
    $contrato = Mayus($obra['contrato']);
    $desc = Mayus($obra['titulo']); 

    $consulta ="INSERT INTO `ficha` (`ninv`, `contrato`, `desc`) VALUES ('".$ninv."','".$contrato."','".$desc."')"; 

    $resultado = mysql_query($consulta) or die(mysql_error()) ; 

    echo mysql_errno($enlace);
}
```

El error que da si el XML tiene el caracter ' es de este estilo:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax near '12345678, 123.04, 0, )' at
>   line 2

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes intentar `addslashes`

> Devuelve un string con barras invertidas delante de los caracteres que
>   necesitan ser escapados. Estos caracteres son la comilla simple ('),
>   comilla doble "), barra invertida () y NUL (el byte NULL). [PHP: addslashes Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php)

```
$consulta ="INSERT INTO `ficha` (`ninv`, `contrato`, `desc`) VALUES ('".addslashes($ninv)."','".addslashes($contrato)."','".addslashes($desc)."')";
```

Sin embargo te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pruebo y te digo. Lo estoy haciendo en local y será siempre en local, por eso no he intentado evitar el SQL Inyection